# Why this error "Cannot update from precise to oneiric with this tool".

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“An upgrade from 'precise' to 'oneiric' is not unsupported with this tool” error while upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126718/an-upgrade-from-precise-to-oneiric-is-not-unsupported-with-this-tool-error)

It says that it can't upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 in the Update Manager, so how can I force it?

The error message given why I try it is "Cannot update from precise to oneiric with this tool".

Comment: bad idea to force - what is the error reported?

Comment: Cannot update from percise to oneric with this tool